# How do you calculate average circulation across a möbius band?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, mobius-band

The surface is given by the parameterization shown in the picture. We are to find the average circulation across the mobius band with the circulation vector <-y,x,0> using stokes theorem if necessary.
[here's a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIRyu.png)

Comment: The problem is interesting, but misstated. They are asking for the circulation of the vector field around the *boundary* of the Möbius strip. At any rate, don’t just post your homework with no effort. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: P.S. The picture makes no sense. I don’t know what your professor is even thinking.

Comment: Do you think that my teacher misstated the problem? I am stuck with trying to find what actually is the boundary of the region. I found the parametrization of the surface to be {Cos[2 t] (2+(-1+2 s) Cos[3 t]),(2+(-1+2 s) Cos[3 t]) Sin[2 t],(1-2 s) Sin[3 t]}, but then I get stuck with how to evaluate the surface integral given by stokes theorem. It expands to something very messy. Also, wouldn't it be invalid to use stokes theorem since the surface is non-oriented?

Comment: I think his idea was to use the symmetry of the band (it can be split into 3 identical parts) and the the average circulation along one of those parts and multiply it by 3 to get the total average circulation. When you split the band into several parts the surface becomes oriented I suppose.

Comment: The boundary is a weird circle. You can compute the line integral. His picture suggests he’s trying to compute circulation along the family of curves for different values of $s$ and average those. The usual interpretation would be to compute the circulation around the boundary, as I first said, and then for some reason he wants “average” — per unit area of the Möbius strip? If he’s try8ng tomget you to apply Stokes’s Theorem, the non-orientability is a big deal. Break it into 2 or 3 pieces? Bit then be careful with whether the boundary line integrals on the cuts cancel. Most do; two don’t.

Comment: okay so I took the line integral of c where c is the parametric curve described by f(t) and the force is <-y,x,0>. I took the dot product of {Cos[2t](Cos[2t]+2),Sin[2t](Cos[3t]+2),-Sin[3t]} and {-Sin[2t](Cos[3t]+2),Cos[2t](Cos[2t]+2),0} and evaluated it from zero to 2Pi and it conveniently simplifies to 16Pi. Now I am trying to find the surface area of the strip by evaluating the surface integral where G(s,t) is the surface however I run into issues here. To convert dS to dsdt I have to take the norm of the normal vector, correct? that comes out to an unsolvable integral with my technology.

Comment: Yes, I’m not surprised. Evaluate it numerically? I think it’s worth having your professor explain carefully what the exercise truly is and why.

Comment: that seems to get me somewhere. I am still new to Mathematica so does this look like a reasonable way to evaluate it numerically?                                       {Cos[2 t] (2+(-1+2 s) Cos[3 t]),(2+(-1+2 s) Cos[3 t]) Sin[2 t],(1-2 s) Sin[3 t]}
Cross[D[%,s],D[%,t]]//Simplify
Norm[%]
NIntegrate[%,{s,0,1},{t,0,2Pi}]                                                                                     I will ask him that and get back to you when he gets an answer. This is unreasonable to do by hand and doesn't make sense in general.